# Change s3 url with application url in spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, amazon-s3, spree

Hi I m working with one `spree` application in which we are using `s3` to store all product images which generate url like

https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/arvindvyas-production/app/public/spree/products/7/product/02.arvind.png?1465865320

we want it should generate `url` like

https://arvindvyas.com/arvindvyas-production/app/public/spree/products/7/product/02.arvind.png?1465865320

I can do it by putting all images in my current server but how we can do it with `s3`

Comment: After you solve problem of the URLs, which appears to be what you're asking, here... you'll also need to know that for S3 to work with *both* https *and* a custom domain name, CloudFront is also a required component in the stack.  By itself, S3 supports *either* a custom domain *or* https  (...s3.amazonaws.com) but not both.  Combining the two requires CloudFront in conjunction with S3 unless you are proxying the requests to S3 through your EC2 servers.

Comment: you mean this url https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com is default provide by s3 and we can also change this with our domain name ?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot you mean to say we can map this url to our domain like we generally do with the heroku application right ? or we can manage it with or s3 account itself ?

Comment: One hostname, e.g. `example.com` can only point to one destination (server, or cluster of identical servers).  CloudFront can be that one system, and forward requests to a different destination, with a different hostname  (such as a bucket) invisible to the user.  It can also use path patterns to choose which back-end, so, e.g. `http://examle.com/asset/*` is sent to the bucket while everything not matching /asset/* goes to your main site, which again has a different hostname on the backend.  S3 will serve http for `example.com` if you name bucket *exactly* "example.com" but no https that way.